# Best way to store multi-type values in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I have an Entity Framework (Code First) table that holds arbitrary values. The values can have types that vary from simple `ints` to full blown `object`s. What is the best way to store this type of data? I have an `enum` that holds all those available types named `TypeEnum`

```
public class Stream
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Idea 1
    public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public double DoubleValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    // Idea 2
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    // Idea 3: Create tables for every value of TypeEnum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to follow your **Idea 1** and have a typed property that matches a typed database column for each of the types that map easily to the database. So integer, double and string are simple enough as you have listed yourself.

For an arbitrary object you would need to serialize it to something like XML or JSON and then save it into a string field. This is more complicated because you need to deserialize it back to an object again when needed in the future.

Comment: Why a string field - why not a BLOB?

Comment: I assumed you would use a serializer that converts to a string. But yes, you could serialize to binary data instead.